# Simple_Smartsheet is there a way to print specfic columns only when printing a row? pprint(sheet.as_list())

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I am running `Python 3.7` with `simple_smartsheet` and I want to read all the rows in my Smartsheet but only print a couple of columns named "`CCC Site Attributes`" and "`CCC Key ID`".  When I run the script with:

```
sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)

pprint(sheet.as_list())
```

After running the script, I get **all the columns** with data in each row.  What I need is only the specific columns above.

Is there a call in `simple_smartsheet` to pull **all rows** with **specific columns**?  I've been referring to the documentation, https://pypi.org/project/simple-smartsheet/ for reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you've linked to, `sheet.as_list()` *returns a list of dictionaries where column title is key associated with the field value*. I don't see anything in the docs to indicate that the functionality you're looking for is supported by **simple_smartsheet**.

That said, seems like you could do this work yourself -- i.e., iterate through the list that's returned by `sheet.as_list()`, filtering each dictionary in the list by the keys you're looking for (and building up a new list of dictionaries along the way, with each dictionary only containing data for the specific columns you're interested in).